# UBUNTU 18.04 ON LIVE USB INSTALLATION HELP

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to make a bootable USB to test out Ubuntu Linux. 
I used Rufus to extract the Ubuntu iso file to my 8GB USB drive. However, when I try to boot using the drive, and select any option (test Ubuntu, install Ubuntu, etc) it gives this errror and some more

```
[ 0.000000] [Firmware Bug] : TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata: please update microcode to version: 0x20 (or later)
```

Is there are way to avoid this/fix it? System specs posted below

System Specs
CPU -i7 6700
GPU - GTX 1060
RAM - 16GB DDR4 2400
SSD (windows) 120 gb
HD - 1TB
USB - 8GB Kingston DT101 2nd Gen

Comment: Possibly a bug, this error is similar to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030316/ubuntu-18-04-on-live-usb-installation-help

Comment: Another user posted a similar error, possibly a bug https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030316/ubuntu-18-04-on-live-usb-installation-help#1030316

Comment: @Noki you've linked to this question rather than elsewhere and you've double-posted

Comment: I was showing another report of a similar issue in 18.04, indicating a possible bug.

Comment: you just posted the link for this question